# Python "Hello World", Why is my code not executing past my first variable?

Tags: python

I am coding from Automate the Boring Stuff and typed this code straight from the book. I have tried to indent and then I get error messages. *It doesn't say to indent in the book. I genuinely do not know what is happening. The output of the code stops at the first variable. I attached an image and will copy the code below. Thanks to whoever takes a second to  help me out with my first code. Much appreciated!

[image: img]

```
# This program says hello and asks for my name.
print('Hello, world!') 
print('What is your name?') #ask for their name
myName=input('Sebastian')
print('It is good to meet you,'+myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?')  #ask for their age
myAge=input(21)
print('You will be'+str(int(myAGE)+1)+'in a year.')
```

Comment: `input` waits for user input, but you don't appear to ever supply any.

Comment: He is right, and your variable name is "myAge" and the print statement is using "myAGE" which isn't the same so that will also error

Comment: `input('Sebastion')` does not return its argument; it *prints* its argument as a prompt, then waits for the user to type something.

Comment: ```input``` is obviously what you wait for the user to give you, whereas you've initialized it, which is not compatible with Python. If you want to give your program a value Yourself, you should no longer use ```input```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After input is like a print command that instructs the user what to do.
Try this:

```py
# This program says hello and asks for my name.
print('Hello, world!') 
myName=input('What is your name')
print('It is good to meet you,'+myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
myAge=input('What is your age')
# bonus: you can also do int(input('What is your age?')) to cast it to int type directly
print('You will be'+str(int(myAGE)+1)+'in a year.')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Jeez, I don't think I will be making this mistake again. I seriously appreciate you taking the time to help me understand what went wrong.

Comment: Glad I can help. Don't worry we get better at coding everyday.

Answer (score 1):

the value that you put in `input()` is just the text that it shows in terminal. the value of input is what does the user enter.

you should code like this:

```
name = input('What is your name?')
print('Hey! your name is' + name)
```

and the output will be:

```
What is your name?Mohammad(User types Mohammad and presses the enter)
Hey! your name is Mohammad.
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any input

Instead of `"Sebastian"` write: `"Enter your name:"`

Then in the console type your name and press enter

Answer (score 0):

input is used wrong at line 4. Use like this:

```
myName = input('What is your name: ')
```